# cmd-let to Import multiple modules powershell

Tags: powershell, import, module

I have been trying to write a cmd-let for powershell that will allow me to run it and import multiple modules at once into any script I am running. I thought I had it working, but now it seems to have stopped. I just want to know if this is even possible, it seems like it would be.

***Command to run for import:***

```
Import-Module .\Tools\Import-Tools.ps1 
$Tools = Import-Tools -ToolsDirectory \$PathToToolsDirectory
$Tools
```

***Function for importing:***

```
Function Import-Tools
{
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ToolsDirectory
    ) 

    # Make sure the path is absolute (Borrowed from Michael Wanke)
    if (!(Split-Path $ToolsDirectory -IsAbsolute))
    {
        $ToolsDirectory = Join-Path $pwd $ToolsDirectory
    }


    #Verifies that the tools directory exists.
    while ((Test-Path -Path $ToolsDirectory) -eq $False)
    {
        $ToolsDirectory = Read-Host "Incorrect tool path entered. Please enter one now or exit"
    }

    #Create $Tools variable containing multiple lines for import.
    foreach ($Tool in Get-Childitem $ToolsDirectory -Name -Filter "*.ps1")
    {
        [string] $Tools= $Tools + "`r`nImport-Module $ToolsDirectory\$Tool"
    }

        Write-Output $Tools
        return $Tools

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: modules are usually psm1 not ps1 files

Comment: I played around with your script locally and could reproduce interactively running `Import-Module .\test.ps1` successfully but as soon as I tried `$tool=.\test.ps1; Import-Module $tool` in a loop through files it didn't work. Maybe you could dot source them and have them loaded via a profile? It's not ideal but maybe it can help you get past the problem. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Import-Module` cmdlet to import multiple modules:

```
# import multiple modules by using the name of the module
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration, ActiveDirectory

# import multiple modules by using a path
Import-Module -Name c:\moduleA.psm1, c:\moduleB.psm1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I am looking for is a reusable piece of code that I can reuse to import modules stored in a certain directory. It doesn't seem to be working. I can't even seem to store them in a variable and then run Import-Module $Variable. It seems like it just doesn't want to accept it.

Comment: Module discovery is based on the paths in $env:PSModulePath. Try to add your module path to it and then use Import-Module to load the modules.

Comment: OK, so I modified it to set the environment path for PSModule, but my code still does not see the functions. 

New line added:
`$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + "$ToolsDirectory"`

Replaced:
`    #Create $Tools variable containing multiple lines for import.
    foreach ($Tool in Get-Childitem $ToolsDirectory -Name -Filter "*.psm1")
    {
        [string] $Tools = $Tools + "`"$ToolsDirectory\$Tool`", "
    }
    
    [string] $Tools = "Import-Module -Name " + "$Tools"`

Comment: Make sure you add a semicolon before the path you're adding to $env:PSModulePath. Once the path is valid Import-Module should be able to discover modules in the path.

Comment: Still no love. Even had a buddy of mine look at it and he can't get it either. I am not sure if this is ever going to work properly.

Comment: It seems that the Import-Module cmdlet doesn't recognize a variable for the name of the cmdlet you are trying to import. I am begining to think this is a limitation in PS. :\

Comment: This worked for me: $f = 'get-regstring'; Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry -Function $f

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks fort the help Shay. I have posted the code in a git repository on github. Please feel free to review and reuse :)
-----------------
Link:
----------------
https://github.com/Originalme/Powershell-Tools.git

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
foreach ($module in Get-Childitem $modulesFolder -Name -Filter "*.psm1")
{
    Import-Module $modulesFolder\$module
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Point the $Env:PSModulePath to your directory so that these modules become visible to this Powershell session.

> Remember: Modules are yet to be imported! Run a loop over this list &
> import using `Import-Module`

```
$ModulePath = "path\to\directory"

# Pointing the modulepath to this directory so that only these modules become visible to the Powershell session
$Env:PSModulePath = $ModulePath

# Removing pre-existing imported modules
Get-Module | Remove-Module

# Iterate over the list of available modules and import
foreach ($module in Get-Module -ListAvailable) {
        Import-Module -Name $module
}

# Check out the list of modules imported
Get-Module | Format-Table -Property Name,Version
```